# NSFetchedResultsController not refreshing properly after setting new predicate

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

My fetchedResultsController is initially created like this (in viewDidLoad):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Cat" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"age"
                                               cacheName:@"whatever"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

This works fine, and results are shown in my table view. However, when pressing certain buttons I want to filter the results. So I do this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = ...; //based on buttons pressed


[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"whatever"];

NSError * error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (error) {
    DDLogError(@"[%@ %@] fetchedResultsController ERROR: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, error.localizedDescription);
}
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

The problem is that the table view does not reload. If I scroll the table view, the cells change based on new data, but the number of sections and rows does not change as it should each time I try to filter.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should update your question with the error message in the comments to the other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to insert and delete the table view rows based on your updated data.

The error message you wrote in the comments to the other answer holds the clue.

Relevant [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html).

What you should specifically read is the text under the title: ***Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections***.

Before this however, as you are changing your `NSFetchedResultsController`, you should check that you implement NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods to manage the changes. There is standard code available from Apple that you should consider including in your table view controller. You should not need to change / override this standard code.

See this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Essentially for the "Typical Use" case you will want to implement the four typical delegate methods:

- `(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` ;
- `(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo` ;
- `(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath` ;
- `(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` .

**In the case** that you've already included these NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods, you may need to consider using the UITableView delegate methods `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` with the methods:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

So you should try using the following code block:

```
tableView.beginUpdates;
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:animation;
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:animation;
tableView.endUpdates
```

You'll obviously need to create the arrays of indexPaths for the insert and delete methods.

Answer (score 1):

you need to delete cache BEFORE any change to fetchResultController

From apple doc : [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)

> If you are using a cache, you must call deleteCacheWithName: before
>   changing any of the fetch request, its predicate, or its sort
>   descriptors. You must not reuse the same fetched results controller
>   for multiple queries unless you set the cacheName to nil.
>
> Optionally, the name of the cache file the controller should use
>   (passing nil prevents caching). Using a cache can avoid the overhead
>   of computing the section and index information.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. For some reason the tableView just doesn't reload, even though the number of fetched objects does get updated. For example I'll start of with 4 sections in the table, but after filtering there will only be 3 objects in the fetchedResultsController, so if I then try to scroll the table, I'll get an NSRangeException crash. [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]

Comment: since you need to change your predicate is best to set cacheName to nil. not seeing the cache to nil make the fecthResultController keeps the section number and row number